# How to get date and time for Social networking sites emails using gmail-api?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail-api

I have been trying extracting a first message from a particular user. In this case first message from facebook. 
Data is extrating fine but the date and time are not returning
Tried with normal messages it is working.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
import time
from datetime import date

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'

def main():

    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

# Call the Gmail API to fetch INBOX

results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q='from:security@facebookmail.com',labelIds = ['INBOX']).execute()
messages = results.get('messages', [])


if not messages:
    print ("No messages found.")
else:
    print ("Message snippets:")

for message in messages:

    msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=messages[-1]['id']).execute()
    print (msg['snippet'])



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the facebook's first message :(Where date and time are not returning)

Hey Shashi Deep, You recently registered for Facebook. To complete your Facebook registration, please confirm your account. Action required: Confirm your Facebook account Hey Shashi Deep, You recently

This is the normal users first message :(Where date and time are returning)

Thanks a lot. On Wed, Dec 12, 2018, 12:07 PM Shashi Deep <shashi.deep@gmail.com>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let me start by saying I am not a Python dev.  However I can read it.

```
msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=messages[-1]['id']).execute()
print (msg['snippet'])
```

The response from the message.get Should look something like this

```
{
 "id": "1684c9dc1f5fe52f",
 "threadId": "1684bfd8ff98b154",
 "labelIds": [
  "CHAT"
 ],
 "snippet": "",
 "historyId": "4608454",
 "internalDate": "1547473633781",
 "payload": {
  "partId": "",
  "mimeType": "text/html",
  "filename": "",
  "headers": [
   {
    "name": "From",
    "value": "Linda Lawton \u003cxxxx@gmail.com\u003e"
   }
  ],
  "body": {
   "size": 6,
   "data": "8J-krvCfpKLwn6Su"
  }
 },
 "sizeEstimate": 100
}
```

by doing     print (msg['snippet']) you are saying that you only want the snippet field. try doing

```
print (msg['internalDate'])
```

If this doesnt help please run the id though try me on this page [message.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%2C%22id%22%3A%221684c9dc1f5fe52f%22%2C%22format%22%3A%22full%22%7D) i would like to see the json response for the message you are having issues with.